# 3 minute switch/timer

Tags: switches, timer

I have a portable mortor mixer that came with a on/off switch.  My mixing time is consistantly 3 minutes long.  I would like to know if it is possible to buy/make a toggle/rocker switch along with a timer that when the switch is thrown, the mixer will run for 3 minutes and then shut off and then the timer reset for the next mixing. This would help me from continously having to look at my watch while working durning batch mixes and help eliminate under/over mixing times.  The material I am working with is a bit messy so a timer with a turn knob would not last long after it got coated with material off my hands.  The motor on my mixer has a rating of 0.55kw,  absorbed current 9.2A, 115 volts, and frequency of 60 Hz.

Comment: Will the timing circuit be inside the mixer's case or can it be a separate unit?

Comment: seperate unit.  there is a access panel for the box that houses the wiring for the switch, motor, power cord, ect. that sits on top of the Mixer motor.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a PIC 10F200 controlling a relay.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use a time delay relay designed for industrial control systems, such as this [820 Series](http://magnecraft.thomasnet.com/item/relays/relays-time-delay-and-sensor/pn-2927#) from Magnecraft.  This relay could be set in 'inteval mode" and installed in series with an existing toggle switch (on the load side).  Then you would just turn the mixer on, and the relay will limit the run time of the mixer to the programmed time.  turninh the power switch off and on again would initiate a new cycle.  Turning off the switch will immediately stop the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

A darkroom timer would be ideal, but finding one that goes 3 minutes (rather than 1) and handles 1000W looks tricky.  Alternatively, one of the 3-minute variety that can't switch that much power could be wired to a relay to do the job.  But at that point, it isn't much more effort to get a microcontroller to do the timing and drive the relay.  This last method is ideal because it lets you set the time pattern however you want, and you can change its behavior if you get new ideas.

Comment: MacGuyver would have used a toaster.

Comment: MacGruber would have gotten into an argument with his son about breakfast foods.

Comment: I like the idea of being able to change the time if necessay because of temp/humidity working conditions.  I am not an EE like my granfather was who worked on the construction of the world world trade centers and Atlanta playboy club...never gotthat key he promised me lol.  My point being if I need to construct the last method, are there diagrams I can get my hands on to help with the process.

Comment: I found a timer switch that i think will work for me ok.                                                     Broan NuTone 61V IVORY 15 Minute Time Control Timer Switch 20A 120V / 10A 240V